# Unity How to StartCoroutine OnApplicationQuit?

Tags: unity-game-engine, exit, coroutine

I want to fire `StartCoroutine(LogOutUser(url, () => { Debug.Log("logOut req done"); }));`, which sends data to server ,on OnApplicationQuit function . however it  gives this error *

**NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
RegisterLogIn+d__16.MoveNext () (at Assets/Scripts/RegisterLogIn.cs:71)***

RegisterLogIn is class of code below

```
void LogOut()
    {

        string url = String.Format("http://localhost:7989/RegisterApi/logout?myTempID={0}", myTempID);
        StartCoroutine(LogOutUser(url, () => { Debug.Log("logOut req done"); }));
    }

    private async void OnApplicationQuit()
    {
        LogOut();
        await websocket.Close();
    } 

IEnumerator LogOutUser(string url, Action onSuccess)
    {
        UnityWebRequest req = UnityWebRequest.Get(url);

        yield return req.SendWebRequest();
        while (!req.isDone)
            yield return null;

        string result = req.downloadHandler.text;

        onSuccess();

    }
```

how can i do this ?

Comment: Can you share what is happening at line 71? Based on the error you are getting, the null reference comes from there. Maybe the object has been destroyed or cleared.

Answer (score 1):

I understand OnApplicationQuit not wait for coroutines because is like another thread and continue with their job.
 You can wrapper your own application quit to handle your logout.

```
public class MyGame : MonoBehaviour
{
    public void GameLogic()
    {
        MyApplication.QuitWithLogOut();
    }
}
public class MyApplication : Application
{
    public static void QuitWithLogOut()
    {
        Quiter quiter = new GameObject().AddComponent<Quiter>();

        quiter.Quit();
    }
}
public class Quiter : MonoBehaviour
{
    private bool isLogOutDone;

    public void Quit()
    {
        string url = String.Format("http://localhost:7989/RegisterApi/logout?myTempID={0}", myTempID);
        StartCoroutine(LogOutUser(url, () => { Debug.Log("logOut req done"); }));
    }

    LogOutUser(string url, Action onSuccess)
    {
        UnityWebRequest req = UnityWebRequest.Get(url);

        yield return req.SendWebRequest();
        while (!req.isDone)
            yield return null;

        string result = req.downloadHandler.text;
        isLogOutDone = true;
        onSuccess();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you start a coroutine in OnApplicationQuit.. the application will quit before the coroutine has a chance to finish, and all objects are being destroyed.

According to this thread a simple Get SendWebRequest is threaded with no dependency on the main thread, so it should be safe to block the main thread until complete.

https://forum.unity.com/threads/http-requests-without-coroutines.495418/

You can try blocking the main thread from returning and wait for your network request, but I think you only have a few seconds before unity will hard terminate in that case.

Try this:

```
void LogOut()
{
    string url = String.Format("http://localhost:7989/RegisterApi/logout?myTempID={0}", myTempID);
    LogOutUser(url, () => { Debug.Log("logOut req done"); });
}

private async void OnApplicationQuit()
{
    LogOut();
    await websocket.Close();
} 

void LogOutUser(string url, Action onSuccess)
{
    UnityWebRequest req = UnityWebRequest.Get(url);

    req.SendWebRequest();
    while (!req.isDone) {
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
    }

    string result = req.downloadHandler.text;
    onSuccess();
}
```